# How does git handle two pushes in active active scenario?

Tags: git

In the case of an active active highly available git server. A repo in GitHub for example, what happens if two people change the same line on the same file and push at the exact same time. The active active load balancer points the two pushes to two different nodes. How is this case handled?

Comment: I dare hope there's a locking mechanism. One push should win the race the other should get rejected with a message saying their repo is out of date. This will be true regardless if the changes are to the same file or not. Any other behaviour would be a horrible bug.

Comment: Git itself does not deal with this. If some hosting service does work as implied here, that hosting service has to do its own locking, which it can implement however it likes. (Git *does* do its own locking when it's running on its own, unshared machine, serializing the pushes. The locking uses files on the file system, so if the two nodes share a file system, the file-system sharer must ensure POSIX-style atomicity for O_CREAT|O_EXCL and for link/unlink.)